# Batch: Create folders from filename (substring)

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, batch-rename

i have loads of files which i want to organize differently. The batch script should create folders with the substring on the left side of the date in the filename.

**Files are now named like this:**

```
This_is_my_file_21.01.29_22-00_abc_115.avi
This_is_my_file_20.09.29_21-10_abc_15.avi
This_is_another_file_21.01.29_22-00_abc_55.avi
```

**Pattern:**

<Name with unknown number of underscores>_<YY.MM.DD>_<hh-mm>_<string with unknown length>_<number n from 1-999>.avi

**Folders should be named like this:**

This_is_my_file <- two files will go into this directory
This_is_another_file <- only one file.

The Problem is, how do I get the correct substring for my folder name?

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "basename=."
for /F "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ('dir *.avi /B /A-D ^| sort /R') do (
   set "filename=%%a"
   setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   

   
   for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!basename!") do if "!filename:%%c=!" equ "!filename!" (
      set "basename=!filename!"
      md "!basename:~0,-23!"
   )
   move "!filename!.%%b" "!basename:~0,-23!"
   for /F "delims=" %%c in ("!basename!") do (
      endlocal
      set "basename=%%c
   )
)
```

Comment: So all of the file names have the form `*??.??.??-*.avi` yes?

Comment: Looks like you are so close. The value of `%%a` is `This_is_my_file_21` and the value of `%%b` is `01.29_22-00_abc_115.avi`. You assigned the first part of the file name to a variable, now all you have to do is substring with -3 because you want to remove the two numbers and underscore. `set "filename=!filename:~0,-3!"`.  Now the value of the variable `filename` is `This_is_my_file`.

Comment: @ jwdonahue yes, all files have *_??.??.??_*.avi in their names

Comment: @ Squashman i tried this before but then i end up with with a value of !filename:~0,-3! in my variable. It seems like i am almost there, but somethings wron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```batch-file
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files\t w o"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.avi" ' ) DO (
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  CALL :countus "%%b"
  IF DEFINED subdir (
   MD "!subdir!" 2>NUL
   ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%b" "%sourcedir%\!subdir!\"
  ) ELSE (
   ECHO Failed pattern check %%b
  )
 ENDLOCAL
)
GOTO :EOF

:: count number of underscores before pattern YY.MM.DD_hh-mm
:countus
SET /a ucount=0
:countusloop
SET /a ucount+=1
SET /a scount=ucount+1
FOR /f "tokens=%ucount%,%scount%delims=_" %%q IN ("%~1") DO SET "str1=%%q"&SET "str2=%%r"
IF NOT DEFINED str2 SET "subdir="&GOTO :EOF 
:: is %str1%.%str2:-=.%. of form np.np.np.np.np where np is a number-pair?
SET "candidate=%str1%.%str2:-=.%."
FOR /L %%c IN (10,1,99) DO IF DEFINED candidate SET "candidate=!candidate:%%c.=!"&IF NOT DEFINED candidate GOTO success
FOR /L %%c IN (0,1,9) DO IF DEFINED candidate SET "candidate=!candidate:0%%c.=!"&IF NOT DEFINED candidate GOTO success
GOTO countusloop
:success
SET "subdir=%~1"
FOR /f "delims=:" %%e IN ("!subdir:_%str1%_%str2%=:!") DO SET "subdir=%%e"
GOTO :eof
```

The "move" command is merely echoed for verification. Remove the `echo` from `echo move` to actually move the files.

Comment: Thx :) That looks really good. I will try that later when I'm home.

Answer (score 0):

This possible solution uses the fact that your filenames have a known number of underscores if you work backwards. All I do is replace those underscores with backslashes, *which obviously cannot already be contained in the filename*. I can then use the relative paths to step up the filename, as if it were a directory tree, until all I have left is the part ahead of the date sequence, which I then replace the backslashes with underscores again. I use the result of that with [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy), which has a move option, and will create the destination directory automatically, if it does not already exist. At the outset, I perform the directory search, in the same directory as the batch-file, using `where.exe`, (you can change that, on line three, from `"%~dp0."` to `"."`, if you want to use the current directory instead, *or `"any other path"` as necessary*). `where.exe` not only treats the `?` wildcard as exactly one character, (unlike the `dir` command which is zero or one), but also ignores 8.3 naming. It therefore treats the `.avi` extension exactly as written, (and not 'beginning with' `.avi`, which `dir`, or a standard `for` loop, would).

Anyhow, feel free to give it a try:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "}=" & For /F Delims^= %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %__AppDir__%where.exe
 "%~dp0.":"?*_??.??.??_??-??_?*.avi" 2^> NUL') Do (Set "}=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For %%H In ("\!}:_=\!") Do (
        EndLocal & For %%I In ("%%~pH..\..") Do (Set "}=%%~pI"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Set "}=!}:~1,-1!"
            For %%J In ("!}:\=_!") Do (EndLocal & %__AppDir__%robocopy.exe ^
             "%%~dpG." "%%~dpG%%~J" "%%~nxG" /Mov 1> NUL))))
```

If you want even further robustness, and do not wish to use a more suitable scripting technology, the following, *extremely complex looking*, version, is the same code, except that it uses [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) to validate the date and time sequence. It filters those avi files containing the following pattern, `_yy.MM.dd_hh-mm_` in the avi filenames, using all dates from the beginning of 1970 up until the end of 2021:

```batch-file
@Echo Off & SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "}=" & For /F Delims^= %%G In ('(Set PATHEXT^=^) ^& %__AppDir__%where.exe
 "%~dp0.":"?*_??.??.??_??-??_?*.avi" 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe
 /RC:"_[789][0123456789].0[123456789].0[123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].0[123456789].0[123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].0[123456789].[12][0123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].0[123456789].[12][0123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].0[123456789].3[01]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].0[123456789].3[01]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].1[012].0[123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].1[012].0[123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].1[012].[12][0123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].1[012].[12][0123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].1[012].3[01]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[789][0123456789].1[012].3[01]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].0[123456789].0[123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].0[123456789].0[123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].0[123456789].[12][0123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].0[123456789].[12][0123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].0[123456789].3[01]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].0[123456789].3[01]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].1[012].0[123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].1[012].0[123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].1[012].[12][0123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].1[012].[12][0123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].1[012].3[01]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_[01][0123456789].1[012].3[01]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].0[123456789].0[123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].0[123456789].0[123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].0[123456789].[12][0123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].0[123456789].[12][0123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].0[123456789].3[01]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].0[123456789].3[01]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].1[012].0[123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].1[012].0[123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].1[012].[12][0123456789]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].1[012].[12][0123456789]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].1[012].3[01]_[01][0123456789]-[012345][0123456789]_"
 /C:"_2[01].1[012].3[01]_2[0123]-[012345][0123456789]_"') Do (Set "}=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & For %%H In ("\!}:_=\!") Do (
        EndLocal & For %%I In ("%%~pH..\..") Do (Set "}=%%~pI"
            SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion & Set "}=!}:~1,-1!"
            For %%J In ("!}:\=_!") Do (EndLocal & %__AppDir__%robocopy.exe ^
             "%%~dpG." "%%~dpG%%~J" "%%~nxG" /Mov 1> NUL))))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this looks really complex in comparison to Magoos answer. If the other one doesn't work i will try yours.

Comment: @Benjamin, if you properly view my answer, the first example I offered, like Magoo's, and your own, does not determine valid date sequences, It is considerably less complex than theirs, one hack of a lot shorter, and I'd wager more robust too. The second example which I've already mentioned myself looks complex is exactly the same code and methodology, just with the addition of some `findstr` matches for date validation. If you don't need the date validation, my opening response is better, no counting, no `call`s no `goto`'s, no 8.3 naming, no `md`, just better. The choice is still yours!